# App Transport Security blocks domain in my web site which is allowed for ATS

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-transport-security, nsapptransportsecurity

I have a website which is http and I have allowed unsecure connections for this website. In my app I show some images within webviews. Problem is in this website I a have a script which requests another domain for analytics it is a tracking code for images. Problem is ATS also blocks the image tracking code although it is https.

"https://gdetr.hit.gemius.pl/_[TIMESTAMP]/redot.gif?id=pz.rqP9lpEkt0cFhrFsGNKdF7H_sYKyg0HOZjw2vH.P.f7/fastid=bwoxjvwdidakztleymhvkizkicmk/stparam=spenbroqnk"

Do you have any ideas

Thanks

Comment: Use nscurl on the command line to test that URL. The server may have some issue with its certificates or ciphers http://timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image tracking code URL using HTTPS. But internally it is using **

> obsolete cipher suite

**.

see the attached image below.
[image]

I took an example of apple site. https://apple.com. This website is using **

> Modern cipher suite

**
[image]
**

Obsolete cipher suite** leads to **security attack of 13**. Because of this reason apple is treating as non secure connection of your website. This is the reason apple showing **ATS** alert. Update your SSL certificate.